# Lazy solution to fold on Stream algorithm (take K elements from result should consume only Q elements from input)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

There is an interesting problem some colleagues and I came up with and are debating and can't seem to wrap our heads toward a lazy solution. Is there one?

This came up while trying to learn functional programming, and we thought of an extension to the simple problem in terms of lazy solution

I'll present the non-lazy problem first (to which we found an easy fold + flatMap solution )

> Let's say we have a word. W
>
> We want to generate all subsets of the word, such that:
>
> For "abcd" the result would be :
> "", "a", "b", "ab", "c", "ac", "bc", "abc", "d", "ad", "bd", "abd", "cd", "acd", "bcd", "abcd"

Basically go char for char and compose the result so far with the current char,
always doubling the result.

The question:

> Can we find a lazy solution to this problem ?
>
> Given:
>
> - the input as a Stream of Char
> - expected result a Stream of Strings
>
> Can we consume the input stream lazily with just enough data to produce only
> the amount of results we need

Here is my solution so far in Scala :

```
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}

class Problem extends FreeSpec with Matchers {

  private def solution(word: Stream[Char]) = foldr(compose, Stream(""))(word)

  def compose(letter: Char, results: => Stream[String]): Stream[String] = {
    results append results.map(word => word + letter)
  }

  def foldr[A, B](combine: (A, =>B) => B, base: B)(xs: Stream[A]): B =
    if (xs.isEmpty) base
    else
      combine(xs.head, foldr(combine, base)(xs.tail))

  "Problem" - {

    "Taking 5 elements from the result should evaluate only 3 elements from the initial stream" in {
      solution(
        Stream('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f').map(
          x => {
            println(s"Applying map on element: '$x'")
            x
          }
        )
      ).take(5).toList shouldBe List("", "f", "e", "fe", "d")
    }
  }

}
```

I used foldr implementation from this [blogpost](http://voidmainargs.blogspot.ro/2011/08/folding-stream-with-scala.html) as I understand the Scala stream does not a lazy foldRight ?

The problem with this solution is that the map put there for debugging shows that the solution is not lazy

```
Applying map on element: 'a'
Applying map on element: 'b'
Applying map on element: 'c'
Applying map on element: 'd'
Applying map on element: 'e'
Applying map on element: 'f'
```

As it uses all elements from the Stream

---

Another solution I tried would be this one :

```
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}

class Problem extends FreeSpec with Matchers {

  private def solution(word: Stream[Char]) = word.foldRight(Stream("")) (add)

  def add(letter: Char, results: Stream[String]): Stream[String] = results.flatMap(result =>  {
    println(s"Composing result '$result' with letter: '$letter'")
    Stream(result, letter + result)
  })

  "Problem" - {

    "Taking 5 elements from the result should evaluate only 3 elements from the initial stream" in {
      solution(
        Stream('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f').map(
          x => {
            println(s"Applying map on element: '$x'")
            x
          }
        )
      ).take(5).toList shouldBe List("", "a", "b", "ab", "c")
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces :

```
Applying map on element: 'a'
Applying map on element: 'b'
Applying map on element: 'c'
Applying map on element: 'd'
Applying map on element: 'e'
Applying map on element: 'f'
Composing result '' with letter: 'f'
Composing result '' with letter: 'e'
Composing result '' with letter: 'd'
Composing result '' with letter: 'c'
Composing result '' with letter: 'b'
Composing result '' with letter: 'a'
Composing result 'b' with letter: 'a'
Composing result 'c' with letter: 'b'
Composing result 'c' with letter: 'a'
```

---

I don't know if I'm going in the right direction. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Final solution** based on [The Archetypal Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21755/the-archetypal-paul) answer

```
  private def solution(word: Stream[Char]) =
    word.scanLeft((Stream(""), Stream(""))) ((acc, l)=> {
      val r = acc._2.map(_ + l)
      (r, acc._2 append r)
    }).flatMap(_._1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
val zs= Stream('a','b','c','d')
zs.map( x => {println(s"Applying map on element: '$x'"); x})
  .scanLeft("")((a, b) => a :+ b)
  .flatMap(_.permutations)
  .take(4).toList
  //> Applying map on element: 'a'
  //| Applying map on element: 'b'
  //| Applying map on element: 'c'
  //| res1: List[String] = List("", a, ab, ba)
```

It's a bit greedier than it needs to be (`take(5)` evaluates `d`) but it is lazy.

Comment: Neat solution, this works like a charm ! Thanks for the help

Comment: Added final solution I went with, based on your answer, without using the permutations

Comment: Ah yes, I'd missed you didn't want all permutations